# Using Sonar Web Service Java client

Tags: java, web-services, sonarqube

This is my first time using the [Sonar Web Service Java client](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Using+the+Web+Service+Java+client). I've successfully downloaded the jar files and have had no errors executing

```
Sonar sonar = Sonar.create("http://localhost:9000", "login", "password");
```

However when I execute:

```
Resource struts = sonar.find(ResourceQuery.createForMetrics(resourceKey,"violations"));
```

struts is null. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Kindly ask me to add any additional information required.

Comment: The url was incorrect. Sonar does not give exceptions if the url, username or password are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "resourceKey" probably doesn't point to a valid resource.

The resource key for a project can be found on its main Sonar dashboard, in the description widget. For instance, on Nemo, you'll find the resource key for Struts 2 on [its dashboard](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/dashboard/index/52046): "org.apache.struts:struts2-parent".

If the resource is a file, then you have to append the resource path to its project key. For instance: org.apache.struts:struts2-core:org.apache.struts2.util.StrutsUtil

Comment: No, the resource key is correct. As sonar is password protected, might I need some special permissions?

Comment: Found the problem: The url was incorrect. Sonar does not give exceptions if the url, username or password are incorrect. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have a documentation page here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Using+the+Web+Service+Java+client

Comment: Can you please tell which is the right url to give as parameter for Sonar sonar = Sonar.create("http://localhost:9000", "login", "password");